# React: Setting state in Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I new to React and pretty new to Javascript so I suspect I'm making a simple mistake. However, I have been unable to successfully apply any fixes I've found online, so now I'll need to ask for help on my specific issue.

I have the some ajax extracted into several helper methods that look like this:

```
function getIncomes(callback) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/get_incomes/January',
    type: 'GET',
    success: callback
})}
```

I would like to call these methods and use the data from their response to set my component state. I would then like to render a table with the data from the state. Unfortunately, I'm simply getting a null. Below is my component:

```
    class ExpensesGrid extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state= {incomes:{}, expenses:{}, savings:{}};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getIncomes(function(i){ this.setState({incomes: i})});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="expenses_grid">
                <table>
                    <tr><th>Incomes</th><th>Default Value</th><th>Actual Value</th></tr>
                    {this.state.incomes.map(row => <ExpensesGridrows row={row}/>)}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And finally here is my error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Overall the issue is that the `this.setState()` is happening in the jQuery function rather than in the component itself which looks to have an entirely different scope. I'd recommend wrapping `getIncomes()` in something like a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or simply using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and returning the resolved success response value so that instead you can utilize `then()` to execute `this.stateState()` upon a successful API call and avoiding the callback structure entirely.

Trying also changing the callback to a lambda `=>` instead of `function`. This will help ensure you have access to scope of the component and subsequently `setState`. I'd recommend to do this in across all your components to consistently ensure you have access the proper `this`. With `function() {}` the value of `this` takes on a different value inside it's body and will no longer provide access to methods such as `setState`. Also you can use the object spread syntax `...` to merge current state `this.state` with the specific update to the `incomes`.

Also as @RohithMurali has suggested, you'd want to confirm the default data type/value of `incomes`. It's unclear how it's coming in from the server, but `Array.prototype.map()` would only work with an array, so defaulting to an object `{}` can cause that error on initial load.

**getIncomes():**

```
function getIncomes() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/get_incomes/January',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            return resolve(response);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

**ExpensesGrid:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  getIncomes()
      .then(i => this.setState({ ...this.state, incomes: i }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err);
}
```

**Fetch (alternative to ajax):**

```
function getIncomes() {
  return fetch('/get_incomes/January').then(response => response.json());
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried with and without the spreaad syntax.. No luck. Still null.

Comment: You will probably then need to show `getIncomes()`. Ideally if it was a promise or similar you could execute `this.setState()` within `then()` or equivalent.

Comment: By "show" do you mean put it in the componentDidMount?

Comment: I mean to please update your question to include the contents of `getIncomes()` to understand the issue completely. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. I see. It's in the original question already. It's the first code block.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. I provided an approach you can take utilizing `Promise` that would allow you execute `setState` in the component rather than the jQuery method. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I will update this comment tomorrow if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the state intialisation in constructor as,

```
this.state= {incomes:[], expenses:{}, savings:{}};
```

The render works intially even before the api call returns, at that time the incomes should be an empty array so that the map will work for 0 length array instead of an object.

Comment: Well, that was a clever idea. It cleared up the null. However, I end up in an infinite loop of renders. I managed to sneak a breakpoint in and at no point was incomes more than an empty array.

Comment: Can you share the api response. I mean what would it log if you put a log at `getIncomes(function(i){ console.log(i);this.setState({incomes: i})});`

Comment: With the current available code snippets i cant find scope for an infinite loop.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know.